# Can't see python in docker container when using docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to build & start a docker container that has python installed on it. I'm using the python3.6 base image. I've specified the following in my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
    product-services:
        build: ./app/
```

The corresponding `app/Dockerfile` file is:

```
FROM python:3.6
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
```

Everything seems successful when I run `docker-compose up`. However, when I log into the container and run `python --version`, there is no output--which means python is not on the container.

But when I manually build the image and run the container, there *is* output from the `python --version` command.

My question is: why can't I see python running when I install via the docker-compose file?

Comment: How are you "logging into" the container?  Do any other commands show output?  You may need to add the `--interactive` or `--tty` option somewhere.

Comment: I'm logging into the container using `docker  exec -it {container id} sh`. Yes, other commands show output--like cd, pwd, ls, etc.